# Defining the behaviour of >>= for a monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm learning about monads in Haskell at uni and this is an exercise we've been given:

Given the type

```
data Expr a = Var a | Val Int | Add (Expr a) (Expr a)
```

of expressions built from variables of type `a`, show that this type is monadic by completing the following declaration:

```
instance Monad Expr where
--  return         :: a -> Expr a
    return          = ...

--  (>>=)          :: Expr a -> (a -> Expr b) -> Expr b
    (Var a)   >>= f = ...
    (Val n)   >>= f = ...
    (Add x y) >>= f = ...
```

So far I've logically managed to come up with:

```
return        = Var

(Var a) >>= f = f a
(Val n) >>= f = Val n
```

But how do you define `(Add x y) >>= f`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case where we can just "follow our noses" by examining the types: when given `Add x y` we have two things of type `Expr a` (`x` and `y`) and we're trying to output something of type `Expr b`. One option would be to just entirely ignore `x` and `y` and output something like `Val 0` (but that's not very interesting, and probably breaks the Monad laws).

Hence, assuming we wish to use both `x` and `y` a good first step would be to transform those two `Expr a`s into `Expr b`s: we have exactly one choice here since there's exactly one relationship between `a` and `b`, the function `f :: a -> Expr b`.

Now, to use these two pieces of information, we can think about looking for a function with type `Expr a -> (a -> Expr b) -> Expr b`, that is, something to take our expression (`Expr a`) and the function (`a -> Expr b`) and give us an `Expr b`.

Seem familiar?

It should: it's exactly what we're working with, the bind operator `>>=`. By using this, we've now got two `Expr b`s: `(x >>= f)` and `(y >>= f)`.

Hence, the last step is to use these two things to give the result: a single `Expr b`... there's a single choice for this too.

Answer (score 4):

This is a game of typing tetris. Let's consider the types of your first two (correct) branches.

```
a :: a
f :: a -> Expr b
----------------
Expr b
```

We read this as "given all of things above the line, we must produce something of the type listed below the line". In this case, the answer is obvious: we just apply `f` to `a`.

```
a :: a
f :: a -> Expr b
----------------
f a :: Expr b
```

---

For `Val n` we can repeat the process

```
n :: Int
f :: a -> Expr b
----------------
Expr b
```

at first this seems impossible, but we have elided a few things "above the line" that are actually available. Importantly, there's this:

```
n :: Int
f :: a -> Expr b
Val :: forall x . Int -> Expr x
--------------------
Expr b
```

and since `x` is not specific (it's bound by `forall`) it can unify with `b`.

```
n :: Int
f :: a -> Expr b
Val :: forall x . Int -> Expr x
--------------------
Val n :: Expr b
```

---

For the final case, we have

```
x   :: Expr a
y   :: Expr a
f   :: a -> Expr b
Add :: forall x . Expr x -> Expr x -> Expr x
--------------------------------------------
Expr b
```

Again, this seems impossible. We could reassemble the `Add` using `x` and `y` but that just gives us a type `Expr a` instead of `Expr b`. We can't apply the `f` because it needs an `a` not an `Expr a`.

So the trick is that with recursive data types you're almost certainly going to use recursive definitions to functions... So let's bring in one other thing we have from the environment.

```
x     :: Expr a
y     :: Expr a
f     :: a -> Expr b
Add   :: forall x . Expr x -> Expr x -> Expr x
(>>=) :: forall y z . Expr y -> (y -> Expr z) -> Expr z
-------------------------------------------------------
Expr b
```

Again, due to the `forall` we can use `(>>=)` on `Expr` types whatever their variable is. Almost immediately we have only one way to go forward: the only value we have that could be the second argument to `(>>=)` is `f`

```
x       :: Expr a
y       :: Expr a
Add     :: forall x . Expr x -> Expr x -> Expr x
(>>= f) :: Expr a -> (a -> Expr b) -> Expr b
-------------------------------------------------------
Expr b
```

And now we could apply either `x` or `y` on the left side of `(>>= f)` to get a value of type `Expr b`. Unfortunately, both of these are wrong. One way to be sure of this is that for highly general functions like `(>>=)` we almost never throw away information—each argument should be used non-trivially.

Fortunately, if we have *two* `Expr b`s we can use `Add` to combine them:

```
x       :: Expr a
y       :: Expr a
Add     :: Expr b -> Expr b -> Expr b
(>>= f) :: Expr a -> (a -> Expr b) -> Expr b
-------------------------------------------------------
Expr b
```

and now we have a way to use both `x` and `y` non-trivially

```
x       :: Expr a
y       :: Expr a
Add     :: Expr b -> Expr b -> Expr b
(>>= f) :: Expr a -> (a -> Expr b) -> Expr b
-------------------------------------------------------
Add (x >>= f) (y >>= f) :: Expr b
```

noting that we keep the `x` and `y` in the same order.

---

So this while game of type-tetris is a bit long-winded but demonstrates that with a few principles:

1. Definitions over recursive types tend to need recursion
2. Definitions of general functions will use every argument non-trivially if possible

we can get to the answer to how to define `(>>=)` almost entirely mechanically. A good definition ought to feel satisfying, like there literally is no other choice.

```
instance Monad Expr where
  Var a >>= f = f a
  Val n >>= _ = Val n
  Add x y >>= f = Add (x >>= f) (y >>= f)
  ...
```

We can interpret this definition as "reacting" the `f` and the lead nodes of `Var` where `a`s exist. If no `a` exists then we're free to do nothing. If recursive `Expr`s exist then we just "push the call to `(>>= f)` down" and rebuild the recursive type.